# typescript callbacks when using third party plugins

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript

In typical javascript, I've been using this pattern when doing an ajax call:

```
myFunction() {
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
  // other options like url and stuff
  success: function () {
      self.someParsingFunction
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the jquery.form.js plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

When posting my form, I did this:

```
var successCallback: (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXhr: JQueryXHR) => void = this.handleResponse;
                var options = {
                    url: "import/upload",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: successCallback
                };
```

The problem is, in my handleResponse method, I can't call other functions of my "class" using `this.someParsingFunction`.  What I ended up doing was this:

```
 handleResponse(data, statusText, jqXhr) {
            window.tempContext.parseInputData(data);
        }
```

Kind of hacky in my opinion.  Is there any way around this in Typescript?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use an arrow function:

```
myFunction() {
  $.ajax({
  // other options like url and stuff
  success: (a,b,c)=>{               // Arrow function
      this.someParsingFunction // Now this is lexically scoped. You don't need to create self
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I do that as the success callback though since the typescript compiler complains that `() => ` doesn't have the expected callback parameters.  The jquery.form.js callback has to have those 3 parameters for the success callback.

Comment: that makes sense, except the tsc compiler complains to me if I don't have the exact parameters that the plugin accepts.  I could modify the plugin, but I was hoping there was another way around it.